# Javascript: Change the ID of a div element and save the value

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code:

```
<img src="{$img_dir}/product_grid_view.png" class="pgrid" title="Grid View" onclick="document.getElementById('product_list').id = 'product_grid'; return false"></img>
<img src="{$img_dir}/product_list_view.png" class="plist" title="List View" onclick="document.getElementById('product_grid').id = 'product_list'; return false"></img>
```

The following code works well and does its job but the main problem is that it doesn't keep the new value saved after I refresh the page and keeps reverting to default value `product_list` which is mentioned in a .tpl file as the following statement: `<div id=product_list" class="clearfix">`.

Any suggestions on this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Swapping ids is a big nono. You could use cookies to keep the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** Not possible (at least, not as in your example).

Javascript is client side and when you refresh the page will be created server side.

If you really want this you should save the value server-side (by using [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)) and use this value when the page is reloaded. But I really don't think you want to be doing that just to swap id's (which is strange in the first place).

Comment: I'm slowly beggining to understand this deal with the client/server side, and the fact that i need to store the value somewhere on my server, but that arises a new question for me! Where exactly do i need to store the 'value'(.php, .tpl - file) and what are the required ajax parameters to change this value (e.g.).

Comment: You might want to dive into "ajax" and "php sessions" first. Check http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_example.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: That will imply to put my unskilled hands on the php files of the platform (Prestashop) wich are triggered from my theme folder(e.g.  `"/prestashop/themes/themename/"` - where all the .tpl files are) and modify them from there. In this case i dont want to modify the php files of the platform or as an alternative method i will need to build a module from 'scratch' (nasty bussines + lack of knowledge). I only want to deal with my .tpl files of the theme and place the code there and do exactly what i ask him to do.

Comment: Here is an example of how to it with cookies http://jsfiddle.net/NickStemerdink/c7d83/.

Comment: And as a side-note the initial solution will cause duplicate ID's which will cause other problems, so you might want to rethink the whole ID switching part.

Answer (score 2):

If you want data to persist between page refreshes, then you have to store it somewhere persistent.

That could be somewhere that is accessible client side (e.g. in a cookie) and then reapplying the changes based on the data there when the page reloaded.

Alternatively, you could use Ajax to inform the server of the change and have the server store the data somewhere (such as in a database) and generate different based on that data when the page is requested.

(The id, however, is a terrible thing to change dynamically).

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing happens only on client side. It does not change your `.tpl` file. In order to get it updated you should send information on server, for instance with [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX), and save new id into database using PHP (as I understand, that is server side language you are using) and populate it in your `.tpl` file next time page is loaded.

At the same time - not clear why do you need to change an ID of an element that way. Looks like you are doing something wrong.

Comment: This seemed to me as a 'handy solution' in the first place, but clearely not as viable as i was expecting it to be. I'm lacking of knowledge, at least on the programming side and javascript language. I will do some research and also keep in mind what you told me and hopefully i will get at the bottom of this problem :) - The platform that im using it for is `Prestashop`. Thanks everyone for your quick replies and help!